# C++ Warning to typedef void (* somename) (arg1, arg2);

Tags: c++, typedef, void-pointers

First... I have the following code in a file named core_ns.h

```
/*
 * the prototype for the function that will be called when a connection
 * is made to a listen connection.  
 * Arguments:
 *    Server_Connection - ID of the listen connection that received the request
 *    New_Connection    - ID of the data connection that was created.
 */
typedef void (* CORE_NS_Connect_Callback)
                (CORE_NS_Connection_Type  Server_Connection,
                 CORE_NS_Connection_Type  New_Connection);
```

I then have the following in a file named ParameterServerCSC.h

```
class ParameterServer{
public:
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //FUNCTION: sendCallback
    //
    //PURPOSE: This method will be performed upon a connection with the client. The 
    //Display Parameter Server will be sent following a connection.
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void sendCallback (CORE_NS_Connection_Type serverConnection, CORE_NS_Connection_Type newConnection);
}; // end class ParameterServer
```

Finally... I have the following usage in a file named ParameterServer.cpp

```
       //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      //FUNCTION: setup 
      //
      //PURPOSE: This method will perform any initialization that needs to be performed
      //at startup, such as initialization and registration of the server. 
      //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      void ParameterServer::setup(bool isCopilotMfd){

            CORE_NS_Connect_Callback newConnCallback; 
            newConnCallback = &ParameterServer::sendCallback;//point to local function to handle established connection.
      }
```

I'm getting the following warning:

> warning: converting from `void (ParameterServer::*)(CORE_NS_Connection_Type, CORE_NS_Connection_Type)' to`void (*)(CORE_NS_Connection_Type, CORE_NS_Connection_Type)'
>   MY_PROJECT/DisplayParameterServer
>   ParameterServerCSC.cpp

Im using LynxOS178-2.2.2/GCC C++ compilier.  My solution builds with this warning.  I am trying to understand the meaning of the warnings.  Any insight to this is appreciated.

Comment: A member function is not compatible with a non-member function, is the gist of it.

Comment: Looks like a flaw in the compiler implementation for me. The compiler should issue an error instead of a warning (IIRC GCC usually does this??). As @ecatmur's answer states the function pointer types are really incompatible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ParameterServer::sendCallback` is a member function or method (its type is `void (ParameterServer::*)(CORE_NS_Connection_Type, CORE_NS_Connection_Type)`) so it cannot be used as a function (type `void (*)(CORE_NS_Connection_Type, CORE_NS_Connection_Type)`).

You need to make it a static member function:

```
static void sendCallback (CORE_NS_Connection_Type serverConnection, CORE_NS_Connection_Type newConnection);
```

Otherwise (depending on calling convention) when the API calls `sendCallback` the parameters will be set up incorrectly and will appear incorrect; at the very least the hidden `this` parameter will be garbage.